# jquery filter by two variables & one of them maybe undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, filtering, each

I'm writing some jquery code to filter li items based on class & data-attribute.
Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/14eLwYWP

The problem is, that when one of the variables is undefined (which happens when user click second time to disable filter), it doesn't show anything. I was wondering that is there any other resolution to this problem, instead of writing code for every case.

I mean, situation is simple, each() filters only when both currentCity and currentAge has values. But when one of them is undefined, I want to show li-items filtered by only another one variable. I don't know how to write it, but I think the main problem is there:

```
$('ul.the_loop').children('li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('age') == 'post_' + currentAge && $(this).hasClass("tag-" + currentCity)) {
        $(this).show();
    } else if (currentAge == undefined || currentCity == undefined) {
        //don't know what to do there, both with logic and code...
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Hope you guys will help me ;)

Have a nice day & cheers!

EDIT: Because this code, as stupid it is, works…

```
$('ul.the_loop').children('li').each(function() {
if ($(this).data('age') == 'post_' + currentAge && $(this).hasClass("tag-" + currentCity)) {
    $(this).show();
} else if (currentAge == undefined && $(this).hasClass("tag-" + currentCity)) {
    $(this).show();
} else if ($(this).data('age') == 'post_' + currentAge && currentCity == undefined) {
    $(this).show();
} else if (currentAge == undefined && currentCity == undefined) {
    $(this).show();
} else {
    $(this).hide();
}
});
```

But there must be more elegant way of doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for equality, so when `currentAge` is undefined your filter breaks because no element has an age of just `"post_"` with no age value after it. (As you already know) so if you use indexOf to instead check if the string contains the phrase `"post_"+currentAge` then it won't break since all of the age attributes begin with `"post_"`. The indexOf function will return the index of where the substring occurs in the string, or -1 if it can't find it.  The idea is the same for `currentCity` and `"tag-"`, but we need a string to look at to do the comparison, so instead of `hasClass` just use `.attr('class')` instead, so its

```
function globalFilter(currentCity, currentAge) {
    $('ul.the_loop').children('li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('age').indexOf('post_' + currentAge) > -1 && $(this).attr('class').indexOf("tag-" + currentCity) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        }
```

EDIT: If you are dynamically changing the classes of elements you may need to use `.prop('class')` instead of `.attr`